# bazel for c/c++ large project with RBE

Tags: bazel

We tried to setup using buildfarm .. in the buildfarm they gave an example to run the server and worker on the same machine (https://bazelbuild.github.io/bazel-buildfarm/docs/quick_start/) In order to use multiple machines as workers for the remote build execution what should be done. Any relevant material to setup the multiple machines as workers in buildfarm it will help.

Comment: Found a [reference](https://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/bazel-remote-execution) Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Found a [reference](https://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/bazel-remote-execution) Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Bazel buildfarm runs an [integration test](https://buildkite.com/bazel/buildfarm-farmer/builds/5624#01856582-d983-41a4-af41-6b764d722d45) that demonstrates multiple containers running to create a cluster.  You can see this [script](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-buildfarm/blob/0ace8ca4fc9668f4089e4338186758aa887e0e85/.bazelci/test_buildfarm_container.sh#L109) that starts the containers and runs a full integration test.

A full production cluster requires, redis, server(s), and worker(s).

For a production use-case, deploying multiple servers / workers will work similarly to the integration test.  Both the servers and the workers scale horizontally and will communicate over redis.  They will also connect to one another automatically via grpc.  K8s example files can be found [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-buildfarm/tree/main/kubernetes).